# Tracking Down Citation for Mixed Model Variance Formula

Tags: regression, mixed-model, references

I have in my notes that [McCulloch and Searle](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/047119364X) write an expression for the marginal variance of a linear mixed model of the general form $\bf{y} = \bf{Xb}+\bf{Zu}+\bf{e}$ as using the trace of a matrix with this general expression

$$
\bf{T} = \left[\bf{I} + \left(\bf{Z}'\bf{Z} - \bf{Z}'\bf{X} (\bf{X}^{'}\bf{X})^{-1} \bf{X}^{'}\bf{Z}\right)\bf{D}\right]^{-1}
$$

Which is also similar enough to equation (115) [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/234016332_Estimation_Testing_and_Prediction_Regions_of_the_Fixed_and_Random_Effects_by_Solving_the_Henderson%27s_Mixed_Model_Equations).

I have programs using this expression which builds accurate code, so the expression is seemingly right. However, going back to McCulloch and Searle I cannot find this exact expression in the book and have also poured through other books/papers. I've somewhat exhausted my search and am appealing to others who may recognize the expression and provide a citation for me to better document.

Can anyone else recognize this form and provide a source for me to review and use as documentation?

Comment: Pff... Ugly. (+1) I thought I had seen it in [Variance Components](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/book/10.1002/9780470316856)(1992) but I can't found it now, do check the book if you can though - sections Chapt. 7.6 d/e is where you want to look at, Eq, 80, 90 and 99. The form you present strongly resembles the Henderson's Mixed Model Equations for variance and I wi